# RunServer seems to be pointing at the wrong file but I don't know why or how to change it

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run my Python `manage.py` server and get an error back but the error seems to be pointing at the wrong file, not sure why this is.
The file it seems to be pointing at is `"Demoproject"` when I need it to be pointing at `"Slidelytics_site"`.

Is there a path that could be wrong or is there a specific `.py` file that holds this path that I can adjust?

Interesting side note - When I remove the below code from the settings.py file, this error does not occur.

Interesting side note - When I remove the below code from the settings.py file, this error does not occur.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # '/var/www/static/',
]
```

PS

```
C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\Slidelytics_site> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03FB7780>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\staticfiles\checks.py", line 9, in check_finders
    finder_errors = finder.check()
  File "C:\Users\trueb\Desktop\demoproject\venv\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.5-py3.7.egg\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 82, in check
    if settings.STATIC_ROOT and os.path.abspath(settings.STATIC_ROOT) == os.path.abspath(root):
  File "C:\Users\trueb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 526, in abspath
    return normpath(_getfullpathname(path))
TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not tuple
```

I am hoping to get a better idea of where to look or what to change in order to resolve this issue.

Comment: whats # in " # '/var/www/static/'" ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `manage.py` usually has a hardcoded reference to default settings it wants to use, or it may read them from env variable. Have you checked both?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is a tuple. As the error message says, it should be a string, bytes or os.PathLike. The most likely cause is a stray comma, something like this:

```
>>> STATIC_ROOT = '/my/static/root',  # <- note the trailing comma
>>> type(STATIC_ROOT)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> STATIC_ROOT = '/my/static/root'
>>> type(STATIC_ROOT)
<class 'str'>
```

If you look at the [source of this exception](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.5/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py#L82), you can see that it's within a for loop that iterates over `STATICFILES_DIR`. By default, this setting is an empty list. That explains why the error goes away if you remove that seemingly unrelated settings.

As for the wrong path, I would guess that you have enabled the wrong virtualenv. Try the `deactivate` command or simply starting a new console/cmd window.

Comment: What would make the Tuple a string?  How do I convert it?  Im a beginner here

Comment: For the STATICFILES_DIR - do I put that link of code under my current STATICFILES_DIR? or in a different place?

Comment: @JasonTrueblood I've extended my example, does that make it clearer? I don't understand your second question, sorry. Maybe update your question with the different approaches you are considering, or ask a new one.